# How to type a Unicode character using its UTF-8 sequence in Vim?

Tags: vim, unicode

`₩` is the currency symbol for North Korea. Its Unicode code-point is `U+20a9`.
In insert mode, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> `u20a9` to type it.
If I only know its UTF-8 form `e2 82 a9`, how can I type it easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same solution with a twist of automation to help remember it:

```
command! -nargs=* UTF8 call EncodeUTF8(<f-args>)
fun! EncodeUTF8(...)
   let utf8str = ""
   for i in a:000
      let utf8str .= "\\x" . i
   endfor
   exe "norm i" . eval("\"".utf8str."\"")
endfun
```

Now you can `:UTF8 e2 82 a9`

You can also type this particular character with `<C-k>W=`. See `:help digraph-table-mbyte`.

Note that you can also get information about a character with `ga` and `g8` in normal mode. So it might be easier to just do `<C-r>="\xe2\x82\xa9"` once and then do `ga` to get the code-point.

Answer (score 10):

I just found this solution:

In insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> `="\xe2\x82\xa9"` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I'd like to know about any other (shorter?) methods, though.